# How to disable the child-components of a nested JPanel but keep the panel itself usable

Tags: java, swing, nested, jpanel, jcomponent

So, in my JPanel I have several components. Becuase I want the user to be able to add components to the JPanel using the mouse, I want to disable all the child-components already present in the panel so the user can't click them when adding new components. I want to know how to disable all the components that are inside my original JPanel. I have tried using the following:

```
for (Component myComps : compPanel.getComponents()){

                myComps.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

The components are located in a nested JPanel, the order would be

JFrame ---> Main JPanel ---> Target JPanel (compPanel in the code) ---> Target Components

Thanks in advance! All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a method which can be used to get all components even if they laid out in nested panels. The method can for example get you all `JButton` objects in your panel. But if you want to disable all components you should search for `JComponent.class`.

```
/**
 * Searches for all children of the given component which are instances of the given class.
 *
 * @param aRoot start object for search.
 * @param aClass class to search.
 * @param <E> class of component.
 * @return list of all children of the given component which are instances of the given class. Never null.
 */
public static <E> List<E> getAllChildrenOfClass(Container aRoot, Class<E> aClass) {
    final List<E> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final Component[] children = aRoot.getComponents();
    for (final Component c : children) {
        if (aClass.isInstance(c)) {
            result.add(aClass.cast(c));
        }
        if (c instanceof Container) {
            result.addAll(getAllChildrenOfClass((Container) c, aClass));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So in your case you must rewirite your loop as following:

```
for (Component myComps : getAllChildrenOfClass(compPanel, JComponent.class)){

            myComps.setEnabled(false);

}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! Though when I try to implement it I get the following warning. "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <JComponent>". I realize this is probably a noob question, but what have I missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VICWICIV Sorry but I cannot answer your question without to see your code. Please also mark my question as useful, so you'll get also some points of reputation ;).

Comment: All right I see, is it okay if I use pastebin? Or should I edit my OP? :)

Comment: @VICWICIV please edit your question and write me a comment here.

Comment: All right. I've added the classes and code needed to reproduce the issue, It's a ton of code but quite skeletonized in comparison to the original program. I realize this is a lot. but any help and pointers would be immensely appreciated. If anything is unclear, just ask.

Comment: @VICWICIV Please use the method I've posted exactly. The method signature must be `public static <E> List<E> getAllChildrenOfClass(Container aRoot, Class<E> aClass)`

Comment: All right it works! :D It was the import java.awt.List that was the problem and caused the The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments-error. Thank you so much for the help! :)